# Open web app with URL scheme?

Tags: ios, iphone, url, web-applications, url-scheme

Is it possible to open a web app (which has been saved to the user's iPhone home screen; I don't want it to open through the full safari app) using a custom URL scheme from a link within an email? I only need it to work on iPhones.

Comment: No,  a HTTP link will always open in safari.

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11, that's a shame. What would be the easiest way to get info from an email (which I generate) into a web app?

Comment: Create a native app.  Or include instructions in your email advising the user to press the home button and open the web app manually.

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11, ideally I love to be able to create a native web app! I keep trying but I just can't get my head around it!!!

Comment: If you know your users and they have individual logins in your webapp, then you could store the information you would have pushed in the email on a server and then just send out "alert" emails. When your users then start the webapp and login, then the stored information can be read by the webapp.

Comment: Thanks @MogensBeltoft, but unfortunately I don't want to store the info on my server as it's particularly sensitive.

Comment: @Brad, I don't get it. You claim to have sensitive information that you don't want to store on a server (possibly encrypted and behind a login), but you're OK with having it sent in an email. Emails are not secured by anything, they are usually not sent encrypted between servers and to and from clients.